# cannot reach web app from docker host (not docker-machine)

Tags: docker

I have a simple web app container running on docker engine for mac (v.1.12.5) using the following:

`docker run --rm -p 80:8089 test-app`

I've checked my container's IP under Networks > bridge from the following:

`docker inspect $(docker ps -l --format "{{.ID}}")`

```
"Networks": {
    "bridge": {
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": null,
        "NetworkID": "f53f1b93aa0f2fda186498d30e7f6e5b97ba952d1b6fe442663ac6025fd74ce3",
        "EndpointID": "178937cf211c2360d9f9c594891985637d1d82a334a40b1b46d3acb2ea8aaf20",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2", // <- use this?
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, I am running my web app container on my docker engine directly on my laptop (not via `docker-machine`).  At this point, I'm not so much concerned with making it work rather than understanding.

My container has an assigned IP `172.17.0.2` which I've pasted above and I've mapped my web app container (with an EXPOSE 80) to port 8089 via the `docker run -p` flag.

I'm under the impression that I should be able to reach my web app at http:// 172.17.0.2:8089 but I just get no response.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the process in the container listens on port 80, your `-p` flag should be the other way round `-p 8089:80`. The service can then be reached at `localhost:8089`.